# Joi validate array of objects with when condition

Tags: express, nodes, hapi.js, joi

First of all, sorry for bad English.

I can't find any docs about this.

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**

```
const docs = {
  type: 'a', // ['a',' 'b', 'c'] is available.
  items: [
    {
      a: 123,
      b: 100 // => This value only available when type is 'a' or 'b'. otherwise, forbidden.
    }
  ]
};
```

**MY JOI SCHEMA(NOT WORKED)**

```
Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string().valid('a', 'b', 'c').required(),
  items: Joi.array()
    .items(
      Joi.object({
        a: Joi.number().required()
        b: Joi.number()
      })
    )
    .when('type', {
      is: Joi.string().valid('a', 'b'),
      then: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({ b: Joi.number().required() })),
      otherwise: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({ b: Joi.number().forbidden() }))
    })
})
```

This code is not working correctly.
When type is 'c', it validate passed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: oops, my version is 16.1.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have added `.items()` to `items: Joi.array()` which overrides the `.when()` condition, try using

```
Joi.object({
    type: Joi.string().valid('a', 'b', 'c').required(),
    items: Joi.array()
        .when('type', {
            is: Joi.string().valid('a', 'b'),
            then: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
                a: Joi.number().required(),
                b: Joi.number().required()
            })),
            otherwise: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
                a: Joi.number().required()
            }))
        })
})
```

[example](https://repl.it/repls/LoneFrigidComputeranimation)